# eval: executing a jquery chain string with dynamic values

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I would like to execute this jQuery string but so far the only way I know how is to use eval, what is a more appropriate way of doing this?

```
var first = thisWay('next')
var second = thisWay('prev')


var thisWay = function(direction){
    var Chain = "$('#img')." + direction + "('div');";

    eval(Chain)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is another way of accessing properties using the `[]` notation. That way you can pass dynamic values as well:

```
$('#img')[direction]('div');
```

To be precise, `$(...).something` is equal to `$(...)['something']`. So passing something after `.` is always a literal string, while `[...]` does not necessarily have to be a literal string.

Comment: Much better than my answer, didn't know you could do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
function thisWay(direction) {
    if (direction == 'next') {
        $('#img').next('div');
    }
    else {
        $('#img').prev('div');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function does have better support since it will never call a non-existing function, so +1.